# Making a new heading style

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am trying to understand styles in Microsoft Word. How do I make a new heading style? Built-in heading style in word have more than just the formatting. They are collapsible in the document, they show in in the document structure, they appear in the table of contents and maybe other things that I don't know. I can modify a built-in heading style and have this effect but If I create a new style from the normal one, I could make it look like a heading but it won't fully behave as a heading: the section will not be collapsible, it will not appear in the TOC nor in the document structure. Are there options somewhere that is related to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your style has to apply to paragraphs, not just single characters. Then just set the appropriate "outline level" in the paragraph format properties:

[image: Word's paragraph style settings]

Answer (score 0):

Mario's answer will give you outline level characteristics to your paragraph styles. It will give the expand/collapse characteristic. It does not replicate all of the features of the built-in-heading styles. Use those if you can. You can certainly modify the formatting to match what you want. The only reason to not use the built-in styles is if you are using them for some other purpose.

This [page by Word MVP Shauna Kelly](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/usebuiltinheadingstyles.html) gives most of the advantages of using built-in heading styles. These cannot be duplicated in custom styles. You can get *some* of them by basing your custom styles on the built-in styles.